# How to pass union type as argument

Tags: typescript

How to make `del` function work?

It complains that `index(v)` has wrong `v` type:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(v: T): number | undefined', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'T | ((v: T) => boolean)' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
      'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | ((v: T) => boolean)'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(op: (v: T) => boolean): number | undefined', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'T | ((v: T) => boolean)' is not assignable to parameter of type '(v: T) => boolean'.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type '(v: T) => boolean'.(2769)
```

```js
class Enumerable<T> {
  index(v: T): number | undefined
  index(op: (v: T) => boolean): number | undefined
  index(op: T | ((v: T) => boolean)): number | undefined {
    return 0
  }
}

class Collection<T> extends Enumerable<T> {
  del(v: T | ((v: T) => boolean)): void {
    const i = this.index(v) // Error
    console.log(i)
  }
}

new Collection<number>().del(0)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiB2BXAtgUwE5gEYlQHgBUA+aAbwChpoBLeAE1QA8AKANwC5oCBKTpZLBmgAfaInqoAZrVR1KNCSwD2AB05tOPaAF4SWJUtxh4vaP0HoRYidPiz5tBsrVcrzDV2469BoydPmQqLiDLayZPJU6KgALojo8NAADPIAvuTp5KCQMADChrjAMdRK8IQkTDGo9DAIKBjYuOURVAwgHgRuHV660PqGqMbcpqxK1HQtVNDApRAxNDrQMQAW1BAAdI5MbF4A9Ltw6OhK6JyR07MD6yBKAObM1NxpGeTkdgDu0PkghcWleIF0ERmNx1m1mEluEA)

If the distinct declarations of the `index` function signature removed, and the union type used, it would work.

```js
  // index(v: T): number | undefined
  // index(op: (v: T) => boolean): number | undefined
  index(op: T | ((v: T) => boolean)): number | undefined {
    return 0
  }
```

But I prefer to use distinct declarations. The code below doesn't work. But it would work if distinct types are used.

```js
class Collection<T> {
  order(op?: ((a: T, b: T) => number) | ((v: T) => unknown)): T[] {
    return []
  }
}

new Collection<[number, number]>()
  // Error: Parameter 'pairs' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  .order((pairs) => pairs[0])
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2IQFNgBcCW8B2AeAKgHzQDeAUNNPAE4Amy1AFPAA4D8AXNI42F-gBpoAI34BKaAF5i2AK4BbYQwkAfbowBu4qcVnYA1tngB3bGLH8A2gF1SFStGrI0s6tmg37AXzI+y2ZGM4RBR0LDxLOUUGISilamtCRjF7AHpU6ABRamoaLgAFMGoweWcGaAByFjAMaggK6Ax5FhAMYAw0EABPaAALSGgwdwqhroa0LpZkADp7aZp6JkZq2ogJaWgVussABmsxIA)

Is there a good way to make it work?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, I removed the another generic T, it was a mistake, haven't noticed it.

Comment: Fundamentally it's because "maybe this or maybe that" can't definitively be used as this _or_ that. If you narrow them, even though both branches do the same thing, it works: https://tsplay.dev/WKraKm. Or given that your overloads don't actually help: https://tsplay.dev/WJrnrW.

Comment: "But I prefer to use distinct declarations" Uh, why?  I guess it doesn't matter, but it's a weird thing to prefer, *especially* if you actually want to call it with a union sometimes.  But okay, fine.  The solution is to add a third call signature corresponding to the union, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/weyldw).  You'll still see the distinct overloads, but now there are three of them.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz please check the UPDATE part of the answer, I explained why I prefer distinct types. I just realised that your solution with THREE overloads, distinct + union actually solves all cases. Yes please add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107) to allow [overloaded functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to be resolved when called with a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of arguments. Until and unless this is implemented, calls to overloaded functions must be appropriate for at least one call signature alone.  Multiple call signatures are not "mixed" during resolution.

In your case, the easiest solution is to just *add* all the desired call signatures explicitly.  This doesn't scale well for large numbers of call signatures; you need something like 2<sup>*n*</sup>-1 call signatures to handle every combination for *n* original call signatures.  But for two original call signatures you only need to add an additional one call signature to get three in total:

```
class Enumerable<T> {
  // call signatures
  index(v: T): number | undefined;
  index(op: (v: T) => boolean): number | undefined;
  index(op: T | ((v: T) => boolean)): number | undefined;

  // impl
  index(op: T | ((v: T) => boolean)): number | undefined {
    return 0
  }
}
```

Now the subclass implementation is fine because the third call signature is selected:

```
class Collection<T> extends Enumerable<T> {
  del(v: T | ((v: T) => boolean)): void {
    const i = this.index(v) // okay
    console.log(i)
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiB2BXAtgUwE5gEYlQHgBUA+aAbwChpoB6a6YMEEaCASwHN4wAXRdVCJWit4AE1QAPABQA3AFzQCASgVJkWDNAA+0RGNQAzEalEBuISPHSA9gAcFshcugBeElmvXcYeCuhqNdG1dfSN4E3MqS0kpOydgqUdFJVd3T29fPwDNHT1xMIjyIVphZFsQC30be0UEpOc3aA8vVB8lLJRA4LzDY1EyISp+XnR4aAAGIQBfchnyUEgYAGEvXGBuVmt4QhJJblQxGAQUDGxcHYGqcRB6uvlk1Kb01syFGWtWfooqKmAtiG4wlc0G4AAtWBAAHTRaQyFIlawAazAAE9BvR-i1ISBrOwpKwlNNZkVwgB3aArJiodabbbZdBEKRKSHXKTjQnzf6A1DAslwNSnHD4AHoETsRlKcyoaFVKQAIjAcsl5GlMKkMEaUNw8HYYOgJAATITVbKALI8UGQzBiazIJnQPATSEAVmgAH5oAq5dAFBqSFqDrrQfroEbTEA)

Comment: Thank you, your idea to use distinct + united signatures, covers all cases.